# In Firebase's realtime Database, does `equalTo(arg)` only work if arg is an object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**db1:**

```js
a: {
  b: {
    c: "d"
  }
}
```

**db2:**

```js
a: {
  b: "c"
}
```

---

```js
db.ref(`a/b`).orderByKey().equalTo('c').on('value', (e) => {
  console.log(e.val()); 
})
```

When referencing `db1`, `e.val()` returns `{c: "d"}`.

When referencing `db2`, `e.val()` returns `null`. Why is this?

---

**Some more experiments:**

```js
db.ref(`a/b`).orderByKey().on('value', (e) => { 
  console.log(e.val()); 
})
```

When referencing db1 & db2, returns `{b: "c"}` & `"c"` respectively.

---

From this, I can only guess that, for some reason, `equalTo(arg)` doesn't like to deal with args that do not object.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalto

have to checked this?

Comment: Are you sure you got `{ b: "c" }` instead of `{c: "d"}` in `equalTo('c')` filter about db1?

Comment: @development-ninja Thanks for spotting that I've edited that now. Question still stands: if you could take another look at the question that'd be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To begin my explanation, I'd say it is not right that equalTo(arg) works only if arg is an obj. No rule about arg's type. Just arg's type will be used during running query but this doesn't mean arg should be an object. arg can be any kind of values like string, char, date, int but not sure it can be an array.

Let me give you some tips on how the above `equalTo` works in your code.
First, in firebase, we implement query by combining sorting(`order-by method`) and filtering(limit-range method) against the path.
In normal way, we use query in this way:

db.ref(path).`sorting function`.`filtering function`.on('value',snapshot=>{});

In your code, orderByKey() is `sorting function` and `equalTo('c')` is `filtering function` applying on result of sorted.
equalTo() will be processed after complete of orderByKey() which returns sorted array. Important thing is that `e.val()` of `equalTo('c')` is also returning JSON object which consists of more than 1 matching obj, not a single result because there will be over 1 result that match to 'c'.
That's the reason why you can see result `{c:"d"}` after running equalTo on db1.

Let's assume you have two obj which has the same key: `c` under `b`

```
a: {
  b: {
    c: "d",
    c: "e",
  }
}
```

Without `orderByKey`, equalTo('c') will run over all objects under `b`.
Then result of running equalTo('c'): `e.val()` will be `{c:"d",c:"e"}` But if you run `orderByKey` before equalTo('c') then equalTo('c') runs on sorted array : `{c: "d"}` but result is still kind of object array not a single value : `{c: "d"}`.

So point is `equalTo('key')` returns object array kind of this style: `{key:"value1",key:"value2",...}` If no result then returns null.
In my experience, if I want to get the value of running query `equalTo()`, I use orderByKey() before `equalTo` and return the first element of the result.
So this works for you.

```js
 db.ref(`a/b`).orderByKey().equalTo('c').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  // important; snapshot.val() will be json object which contains more than 1 matched objs  not a single key-value object.
  const result = snapshot.val(); 
  const value = Object.values(result)[0];
  console.log("value",value);
})

// db2 also works the same. just it has deep 1 less than db1. but the same.
```

Comment: db2 returns `null`. Why is this? It should return `"c"`. The only reason I have to explain this is that, for some reason, `.equalTo` only likes if the value it's looking out for is a JSON object.

Comment: `.equalTo` checks keys not values. db2 doesn't contain object which has key:"c" under path. So it returns null. According to what sorting function you used before equalTo, it checks in different method. In your example, `equalTo` checks keys on sorted because it is after `orderByKey`

Comment: You could see examples of how to use sorting and filtering in combination. Let me know if it doesn't make sense yet.

Comment: `.equalTo checks keys not values` - yes, this is what I tried to mean earlier when I said that `.equalTo doesn't like to deal with args that're not objects`. It seems a query with `.equalTo` has to return an object but a query with just `.orderByKey()` can return a primitive data-type?

Comment: That depends on what path are you running query on. `.orderByKey()` order results by child keys. Results is coming from `db.ref('a/b').on` which returns `"c"` in db2 so the `orderByKey()` doesn't change result as `"c"`

Comment: Ok? So in your example,if child under b is not object then  `db.ref('a/b').orderByKey().on` will be same to `db.ref('a/b').on`

Comment: Am I the only one who finds these rules idiosyncratic? `equalTo` only works if the value you're looking for, in the db, is an object. Without `equalTo`, it works fine if it's just a primitive data-type